# Is this '??' is a operator in php or what it's called? Also is it used for empty() or isset() check?

Tags: php, operators, php-7

`$name = $username ?? '';`

I don't know actually what is this `??`  called?

Comment: It's the "null coalescing operator" (seems it has been answered in SO before...)

Comment: May be but Thank you for answering. I couldn't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

?? is Null coalescing Let suppose

```
$x = expr1 ?? expr2
```

Returns the value of $x.The value of $x is expr1 if expr1 exists, and is not NULL.
If expr1 does not exist, or is NULL, the value of $x is expr2.Null coalescing  Introduced in [PHP 7](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php).

Other Examples

```
<?php
   // variable $user is the value of $_GET['user']
   // and 'anonymous' if it does not exist
   echo $user = $_GET["user"] ?? "anonymous";
   echo("<br>");
  
   // variable $color is "red" if $color does not exist or is null
   echo $color = $color ?? "red";
?>
```